# No MembershipEvent type=removed when a node restarts quickly

Tags: hazelcast

I'm writing sort of auto-rebalancing cluster-wide singleton manager which uses hazelcast's MembershipListener to track up/down events:

```
    hazelcastInstance.getCluster().addMembershipListener(new MembershipListener() {
        @Override
        public void memberAdded(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
            log.info("{}: got memberAdded event {} ", thisInstance, membershipEvent);
            rebalanceLiveNodes(membershipEvent.getMembers());
        }

        @Override
        public void memberRemoved(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
            log.info("{}: got memberRemoved event {} ", thisInstance, membershipEvent);
            rebalanceDeadNodes(membershipEvent.getMembers());
        }

        @Override
        public void memberAttributeChanged(MemberAttributeEvent memberAttributeEvent) {
        }
    });
```

However, looks like if a node restarts quickly enough it does not fire "removed" event but just "added":

```
2015-03-25 16:33:17.736  INFO 21612 --- [        ] [cached.thread-3] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.107]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-25 16:34:02.408  INFO 21612 --- [        ] [cached.thread-4] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-25 16:49:41.160  INFO 26759 --- [        ] [cached.thread-1] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-25 16:52:05.635  INFO 29135 --- [        ] [cached.thread-4] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberRemoved event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=removed} 
2015-03-25 16:52:20.000  INFO 29135 --- [        ] [cached.thread-5] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-25 20:46:29.040  INFO 11780 --- [        ] [cached.thread-3] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.107]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-25 20:47:04.547  INFO 11780 --- [        ] [cached.thread-6] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-26 00:46:39.974  INFO 22198 --- [        ] [cached.thread-4] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.107]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-26 00:47:17.475  INFO 22198 --- [        ] [cached.thread-5] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-26 04:46:50.135  INFO 31576 --- [        ] [cached.thread-2] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.107]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-26 04:47:30.472  INFO 31576 --- [        ] [cached.thread-1] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-26 08:46:25.538  INFO 9252 --- [        ] [cached.thread-4] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.107]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-26 08:47:02.734  INFO 9252 --- [        ] [cached.thread-3] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-26 12:46:32.546  INFO 18528 --- [        ] [cached.thread-1] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.107]:4242,type=added} 
2015-03-26 12:47:14.577  INFO 18528 --- [        ] [cached.thread-4] n.i.i.m.s.b.AmqpHazelcastBalancer        : Member [10.140.140.106]:4242 this: got memberAdded event MembershipEvent {member=Member [10.140.140.108]:4242,type=added}
```

We use Hazelcast 3.2.
Is it normal to not receive "removed" events on node restart?..